disk of convergence of composition of p-adic functions
I watched a video that sketched out the regions of convergence for both the p-adic logarithm and the p-adic exponential functions. I thought about all this and asked myself:

How would I find the region of convergence of $f(x)=\exp\bigg( \frac{1}{\log_p x} \bigg)$?

Well I know that the disk of convergence for $\log_p (x)$ is $D(1,1^-)=\big\lbrace x\in \Bbb C_p: |x|_p<1 \big\rbrace$, and I also know that the disk of convergence for $\exp$ is $D(1,r_p^-)=\big\lbrace x\in \Bbb C_p : |x|_p<r_p \big\rbrace $ where $r_p=|p|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}.$
So would the disk of convergence of $f$ be $D= \big\lbrace x\in \Bbb C_p: |x|_p<\exp\bigg(\frac{p-1}{\log_p |p| }\bigg)\big\rbrace?$

Keith Conrad has this excellent note on $p$-adic series: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf. He is also active on this site (@KCd) and might guide you to an answer.

Some things to watch out for, your disks of convergence have a slight mistake, for each disk respectively: $D(1,1^-)=\big\lbrace x\in \Bbb C_p: |x-\color{red}{1}|_p<1 \big\rbrace$ and $D(\color{red}{0},r_p^-)=\big\lbrace x\in \Bbb C_p : |x|_p<r_p \big\rbrace$. I recommend Alain M. Robert's A Course in p-adic Analysis ch6 sec1.5 - there may be ambiguity in the question since the convergence of the power series with $x$ plugged in to the rearranged coefficients of $(f \circ g)(x)$ may converge while $f(g(x))$ where the value $g(x)$ is plugged in may not lie in the region of convergence of $f$.

@Merosity is there a way to ameliorate that discrepency?

@TorstenSchoeneberg I did not get notified when you posted the above comment. Maybe the @+name has to be at the start.

The expression $\exp(1/\log x)$ seems as strange in $p$-adic analysis as it looks in real analysis: is there a compelling reason to be interested in this, or is it just a random question? The $p$-adic log converges on a disc containing $1$ and $\log(1) = 0$. When $|x-1|_p < (1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$, $|\log x|_p = |x-1|_p$, so $|1/\log x|_p = 1/|x-1|_p > p^{1/(p-1)} > 1$, which implies $1/\log x$ isn't in the domain of convergence of the $p$-adic exponential. I think your question is not going to lead somewhere useful.

@KCd Okay so there is no disk of convergence gotcha. I do have good reason to be interested in this but haven't convinced anyone else yet

I think the tagging only leads to a notification if that person has already commented on the same question --- but then regardless of where it's placed in the comment, which I'm testing herewith @KCd.

@TorstenSchoeneberg yes, now it worked.

@KCd any insight as to why $\exp(1/\log x)$ is a valid function in real analysis whereas does not have a disk of convergence in p-adic analysis?

@KCd for example: for $x\in(0,1)$ the Mellin transform over this portion of the real line exists for $\exp(1/\log x)$. Curious as to why that might fail for the p-adic case.

The $p$-adic exponential has a finite radius of convergence, $(1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$, so you can’t apply that function to large numbers like $1/\log x$ when $x$ is near $1$. I am also not convinced such a composition is worthwhile in real analysis even though it makes sense.
